# How to make BeautifulSoup "understand" the plus html entity

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Let's say we have an `html` file like this:

**test.html**

```
<div>
<i>Some text here.</i>
Some text here also.<br>
2 &plus; 4 = 6<br>
2 &lt; 4 = True
</div>
```

If I will pass this `html` into `BeautifulSoup` it will escape the `&` sign near the `plus` entity and output `html` will be something like this:

```
<div>
<i>Some text here.</i>
Some text here also.<br>
2 &amp;plus 4 = 6<br>
2 &lt; 4 = True
</div>
```

Example `python3` code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('test.html', 'rb') as file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the description of different parser libraries: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser:

This could solve your problem:

```
s = '''
<div>
<i>Some text here.</i>
Some text here also.<br>
2 &plus; 4 = 6<br>
2 &lt; 4 = True
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html5lib')
```

And you get:

```
>>> soup

<html><head></head><body><div>
<i>Some text here.</i>
Some text here also.<br/>
2 + 4 = 6<br/>
2 &lt; 4 = True
</div></body></html>
```